# Django | NoReverseMatch at /installation/ 'elements_app' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

Un template me devuelve un errro relacionado con las url. La url existe (es la que muestro en el código). Pero por algún motivo la aplicación se cree que no está. ¿Qué puede estar mal?

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**element>url.py**

```
from django.urls import include,path
from . import views

app_name = 'elements_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.ElementListView.as_view(),
        name='list_element'
    ),
```

**element>views.py**

```
class ElementListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Element
    template_name = 'element/list_element.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
        if name:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(installation_element__name_installation__icontains = name)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')
```

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes compartir el archivo **urls.py** del proyecto?

Comment: Efectivamente en urls.py estaba la linea correspondiente a esta app desactivada. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ese es un error que a mí también me llevó de cabeza los primeros días con Django.

Resulta que si utilizas el nombre de la aplicación para las URLs, deberías definir una línea extra en el fichero `urls.py` de tú aplicación, independientemente de que ese nombre ya esté especificado en el fichero `apps.py`:

```
# /users_app/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
…

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [ … ]
```

ese es el nombre que está buscando y el motivo por el cual te da problema.

También es necesario que las URLs de tu aplicación estén incluidas en el fichero de urls general con ese nombre, pero supongo que eso ya lo tienes hecho:

```
# urls.py del proyecto general

urlpatterns = [
    path('usuarios/'), include('users.urls', namespace='users_app')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Debo decir que yo me limito a poner *estrictamente* el nombre de la app, esto es, utilizaría `users:user-login` en lugar de `users_app`, pero en realidad no he probado si hay inconveniente en cambiar el nombre.